# Measure theory: upper bound for a particular set

Tags: measure-theory

I have the following problem: consider $A_1,...,A_N$ Borel set on [0,1] with measure greater than 1/2. For every a real number between $0$ and $\frac{1}{2}$, consider the set $E_a$={$x$| $x\in A_j$ for more than $aN$ values of j}. I want to prove that $$m(E_a)\geq \frac{(1-2a)}{2(1-a)}$$

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f=\sum_{j=1}^N\chi_{A_j}$. Then $$\int_0^1f>N/2.$$On the other hand $$\int_{E_a}f\le Nm(E_a)$$and $$\int_{[0,1]\setminus E_a}f\le aN(1-m(E_a)).$$So $$N/2<Nm(E_a)+aN(1-m(E_a))=N(a+(1-a)m(E_a)),$$or $$m(E_a)>
\frac{\frac12-a}{1-a}.$$